# A picture a word Game

Tags: javascript, html, game-center

I am making a guessing picture game like 4 pic one word.So I have all the code and everything about writing the word and guessing the word. But, I don't know how to connect the picture with the word. 
Example. I have a picture of the Cat and the user need to write cat and he will get correct answer.

But how do I connect the picture cat with the word cat ?
I am using HTML5 , Javscript.

Thank you in advance

Comment: minus voters: at least have the courage to provide reasons for minus voting.

Comment: Are you using pure html5 with JS or do you use any database for these quiz questions?

Comment: for the moment I will do it static using html5 and javascript only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make an input field

```
<input id ="text"></input>
<button onclick="myfunction()"></button>
```

Also give the image id and name like

```
<img id="img" name="word">
```

Then in javascript make myfunction()

```
  function myfunction(){
        if(document.getElementById("text").value == document.getElementById("img").name){
        alert("Correct");
      }
      }
```

I m not sure if it is the best way to do it tho

Answer (score 0):

Search for image validation techniques or more correctly the way developers do 'captcha' verification in html forms. For example - We have a number in the image which user have to enter correctly and form is only submitted if users enters the correct number in the textfield present besides the image.

Let me know if you need more details.

EDIT: You can also add the name that you want to check for your images as an 'alt' or 'class' attribute of the 'img' tag and then check if the word entered in the textfield is same as the value of 'alt' or 'class' in 'img' tag.

Hope it helps.

Comment: minus voters: at least have the courage to provide reasons for minus voting.

Comment: sorry I did not mean to vote . Pressed it by mistake . Thank you so much for the respond. I am tryin to figure it out how to do it.

Comment: no problem @Besa. Thanks for taking it back :)